# PHP: Using unpack on a File without Overloading PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, memory, time

I'm trying to create an array from a file using PHP's unpack function. The problem is that PHP runs out of memory when working with bigger files. The script should handle files between 3 and 4 MB when done, but still stay reasonably fast.
Here's the basic idea:

```
<?php
$file = 'uploads/file.pcg';
$array = unpack('C*', file_get_contents($file));
?>
```

Is there a way of producing the array from the entire file at once without overloading PHP , or is my only option to work with a reasonable amount of data per script instance?
- About 1 MB seems to be reasonably fast.
- Could it be that even the array alone would need more memory than the allowed limit?

Also... Sorry if something similar has already been posted here - I don't think it was, though. :D

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is this supposed to accomplish to begin with? PHP's "byte arrays" are simply strings. `$byte_array = file_get_contents($file);`, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you must increase [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your ini file as file_get_contents will load whole file into a memory. Basically, if you want to get a large array - you must do that anyway. Or you may look for other way to read file and unpack it step by step, without reading whole file into a memory.